# XCode 4.5 crash while opening project

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I'm  getting strange issue with Xcode, While opening my Project it's indexing and after 3 or 4 seconds it is getting crashed with crash report as shown in below image:-

[image]

It is happening for only one project not for others. Please help and guide me ...

Comment: Had the same problem, it had something to do with the source control. Open a different project and delete the one projects repository. Try to open the project again

Answer (score 0):

If your machine have another xcode version. Then open the project into that xcode version and close the project. Then open the project in xcode version 4.5

Comment: No only one and i am working fine one week ago with same project in my machine with same configuration.. :)

Comment: You can try deleting the contents of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/